# how to draw an ellipse with given equation in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I want to draw an ellipse in Matlab; but after I google it, I find that all the method needed to draw required semiaxes a and b which I do not know from the equation; could anyone tell me how to draw a plot given any equation, or just give me a tutorial to do that?

P.S: the equation is `r=a(1-e^2)/(1-e cosθ) where a = 17.9, e = 0.967276`

Answer (score 2):

You could do a sweep over a collection of finely-spaced θ-values from `0` to `2*pi`, then calculate the `x` and `y` coordinates.

```
a = 17.9;
e = 0.967276;
points = 1000;
theta = 0:2*pi/points:2*pi; 
theta = [theta 2*pi+1/points]; % add extra point to close the curve

r = a*(1-e^2)/(1-e*cos(theta));
x = r.*cos(theta);
y = r.*sin(theta);

plot(x,y);
axis equal;
```

You might also be interested to know that the eccentricity `e` of an ellipse is [defined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Eccentricity) as `e = sqrt((a^2 - b^2)/(a^2))`, so you could use this to get `b = a*sqrt(1 - e^2)`

Comment: Good and simple solution, however I would rather use element-wise calculations (using the `.`) instead of a `for`-loop e.g. `r=a*(1-e^2)./(1-e*cos(theta));`, `x = r.*cos(theta);`, `y = r.*sin(theta);`. This avoids the `for`-loop and the initialization of `x` and `y`.

Comment: Further `axis equal` after the plot prevents a disturbed view on the ellipse.